# Spring Boot Configuration Not Working

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring boot.

I have an `application.yml` in `src/main/resources`.  I then have a Configuration class that I am trying to get to load the `application.yml`.  However, when I try to use the configuration class in another bean, the values are null.  See the `ApiHelper.java` as to where the values are null.

I'm attempting to run the jar as so:

```
java -jar build/libs/app.jar
```

Am I doing something wrong?  I've also tried using a properties file instead.  When I unzip the jar file the configuration files are in the root.

**src/main/resources/application.yml**

```
spring: 
    profiles.active: default
---
spring:
   profiles: default
api:
   path: http://some-path
---
spring:
   profiles: qa
api:
   path: http://some-path2
```

**src/main/java/AppConfig.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ApiConfig.class)
public class AppConfig {
    @Autowired
    private ApiConfig apiConfig;

    @ConfigurationProperties(value = "api", exceptionIfInvalid=true)
    public static class ApiConfig {
        private String path;

        public ApiConfig() {
            System.out.println("Am I getting called?");  // yes it is
        }

        public String getPath() {
            return path;
        }
    }

    @Bean
    public ApiHelper getApiHelper() {
        return new ApiHelper();
    }
}
```

**src/main/java/ApiHelper.java**

```
public class ApiHelper {
    @Autowired
    private ApiConfig apiConfig;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        System.out.println(apiConfig); // prints ApiConfig@168498d6
        System.out.println(apiConfig.getPath()); // prints null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that you need a setter to make it work:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(value = "api", exceptionIfInvalid=true)
public static class ApiConfig {
    ...
    public void setPath(String path) {
        this.path = path;
    }
}
```